Getting error while opening document or while editing via WOPI for few specific docx file
I have implemented WOPI for web and it works perfectly fine in most of the cases. Also all the mandatory test cases are getting passed. But for few specific documents either i get the error
Sorry , this document can not be opened for editing. or sometimes the document opens via WOPI and whenever i edit the document and close it, WOPI does not call the Post endpoint for contents basically to update the file. It directly calls the unlock endpoint so whatever changes i made in file are gone.
So when i say specific document i mean that -> There are some document where we use libre office to edit the content of docx file via code and then save it to blob storage. So only for those document i get the above issue. I believe some issue is happening while editing the content but i can not wrap my head around what could be the issue. because if the issue was actually with the document or its buffer then i would not even be able to open the document in local .
I tried with multiple documents to edit via wopi but i found that whatever document i updated via libre office via code it does not work in wopi

Since the docx (and other Office Open XML) files are just a bunch of zipped XMLs, I'd suggest the following approach:

Create a docx file, verify it works, and back it up
Perform a little change of the file using LibreOffice
Make sure the file's broken via WOPI
Unzip both docx files and compare the folder and file contents (e.g. using Beyond Compare)
Identify the change that breaks the file. You can then consult the change with the OpenXML standard and take further steps.

If you're running your WOPI client on-prem (OWA, OOS), you can also check out the Event Viewer using the method described here.
